# problema con dependencias en firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase

he estado tratando de conectar mi firebase con android pero me sale un error en

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'**

no se como resolverlo si me pudieran ayudar

no se cual es el problema ya he puesto la implementacion de firebase y no puedo solucionar el error

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En la dependencia que estas tratando de agregar en auth, existen 2 versiones, automaticamente esto lo pone desde android studio cuando conectas Firebase, en esta parte

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0 <--- dos versiones
```

deberias dejar solo una, puedes reemplazarlo por la ultima version

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0
```

Puedes chequear las ultimas versiones de cada componente aqui (paso el link en ingles por que la documentacion en español esta desactualizada en la tabla de versiones)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

tienes que descargar el google services jason  y despues tienes que tener los plugins de internet, firbase, i el del mismo jason, por cierto cuando creas el firebase tienes que poner el mismo nombre que el proyecto de android studio.
'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4','com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'.

Comment: mira por favor [answer]